# What is the read speed of the SSD in the Macbook Air A1466 model?

Tags: ssd, performance

I'm having trouble finding a figure or proper specs on Google, and I was wondering how fast it is.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](http://vr-zone.com/articles/pcie-ssds-in-2013-macbook-air-gives-extremely-fast-readwrite-speeds/36794.html?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=pcie-ssds-in-2013-macbook-air-gives-extremely-fast-readwrite-speeds), it's over 700MB/s.

Comment: So then would one of the USB ports be a bottleneck in transferring things off the drive via USB?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on our exact model so look it up [here](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=A1466).

It can be as high as 6 Gb/s.